# use of ! operator before a function call

Tags: c++

I encountered a code with the function arithmetic(), basically, for multiplication, the thing that bothered me was the use "!" the NOT unary operator before the function call.
code goes like:-

```
    #include<iostream>
    using namespace std;
    
    int arithmetic(int,int);
    int main()
    {
       return !arithmetic(11,9);
    }
    
    int arithmetic(int a, int b)
    {
        return(printf("%d",(++a*--b)));
    }
```

p.s:- removing the ! operator brings no change to the result.

Comment: It `NOT`s the result of the function call.

Comment: Note that `printf` returns the number of chars actually printed.

Comment: It nots the return value not what the function does. Check the program return value and I am sure it does change

Comment: You should make the function main() return 0 if there is no error. If there is any error, then the function main would return a non-zero.

Comment: thanks, everyone I understood the purpose of the use of ! operator.

Comment: `printf` returns the number of chars written on success and a negative value, if there's an error. The operator `!` interprets the operand as `bool` and any non-zero operant is converted to `true` which is always the case (either there's an error or at least one char is written) and the result of the negation is `false` which, when converted to bool yields `0`. This code is just confusing and probably incorrect for this reason (we'd expect a non-zero exit code on an error).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return !arithmetic(11,9);` applies the `!` (not) operator to the result of `arithmetic(11,9)`. That is, it converts the result of `arithmetic(11,9)` to a boolean value and inverts it. Thus it's `true` when `arithmetic(11,9)` returned 0 and `false` in any other case.

This boolean value will be converted to an integer again, because `main` returns `int`. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) covers what the return value of `main` means.

Now the result of `arithmetic(11,9)` is the result of `printf("%d",(++a*--b))`, which is the number of characters printed or a negative value in case an error occurred.

---

All in all `main` will return `0` when `printf` printed any characters *or* if an error occurred (because `!negativeInt == true`) and it will return `1` if and only if no characters where printed and also no error occured. So it's not really usefull here.

Answer (score 0):

When a function returns a value, the `!` (i.e Logical negation operator ) negates the value.
It is mainly used with the boolean values.

As your function `arithmetic` is only printing something. The returned value is never used anywhere. Hence, you are not seeing any effect even after removing the `!` symbol.

Comment: Suppose `arithmetic()` returns `5`. You "negate the value" and get what?

Comment: @Evg: `!5` gives you `0`

Comment: @Elliott No, it gives `false`.

Comment: @Elliott
As mentioned above, it considers value from a boolean perspective. So,
0 => false
+ve integers => true

Hence, !5 is first converted into 0 and it is interpreted as false.